# Accessing Switch data using Net-SNMP in Python with snmpV3

Tags: python-2.7, net-snmp

i m trying to making a snmpV3 manager porgram in python using net-snmp the code is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import netsnmp 

session = netsnmp.Session(DestHost='192.168.1.1', Version=3, SecLevel='authNoPriv',         AuthProto='MD5', AuthPass='password', SecName='user')
vars = netsnmp.VarList(netsnmp.Varbind('ifDescr'))
result = session.get(vars)

print result
```

But result is a tuple (None,)

Can anyone help me about this ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. The Python binding for SNMPv3 is available for net-snmp 5.7.1. Install it then go to `python/` directory and execute following commands:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install (as a root user)
```

Comment: yes SNMP v3 works . it is required to enable SNMP v3 in the device you want to poll